# pyarmor encryption is not secure?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyarmor

I have created one python file recently and then I added login system in it with date validation.
I obfuscate it by using pyarmor `pyarmor obfuscate foo.py` and given to my paid users.
They run my file and they got one `foo.pyc` file and then they opened it and they got my all code in binary digits but they can bypass my login system and they can use my file for lifetime. What can I do to hide my python file and foo.pyc? If i will use `pyarmor pack foo.py` it will converted into .exe file so they can get my source code? they will get .pyc file?

When I try to convert obfuscated python file to exe using pyarmor it shows an error `DO NOT pack the obfuscated script, please pack the original script directly` if I will try to obfuscate original file directly it will come in decrypted pattern or encrypted pattern?

Comment: They will get .pyc file in exe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `pyarmor pack foo.py` but I am not sure that they can wether decrypt or not.